# GVR's native UI layer is missing on iOS

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, google-cardboard, google-vr

I'm currently developing an AR+VR app using GoogleVR and Vuforia on Unity iOS. Everything works fine, but at some point (I don't remember since when!) Google's native UI layer(vertical alignment line, back button, setting button,...) is missing and I can't change the viewer profile.

Versions are: Gvr 1.10 + Vuforia 6.2

So I tried to manually call the `ShowSettingsDialog()` in GvrViewer.cs, but it won't work either.

A new project with fresh sdk has no problem, so it would be specific to my project. I doubt the NativeUILayer would be affected by Unity's camera settings, layers, Canvas settings or so.

I can't figure out what might cause this kind of problem. So I need any suggestions to narrow the cause.

Comment: If a problem could only be found by uploading a whole Unity project, the question would be too broad to answer. Questions have a ~30K limit for that reason (and arguably that's too large).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I also use a custom SDK OpenCVForUnity, and the plugin OpenCVForUnityAppController.mm causes the problem.
It also attach RenderDelegate, sets GraphicsDevice etc.
It looks like that it overrides GoogleVR's iOSDevice so GVR couldn't figure out what device this is.